# Form Switch from Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm using a Creative Tim template for my first Laravel project: Argon Pro 2 for Laravel, I can't get the form-switch field formatting to work for me using eloquent for my Crud. No problem with HTML. Any ideas?

With HTML (Blade):

```
<div class="form-check form-switch">
<input id="repetition" name="repetition" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="CheckRepetition" value="{{ old('repetition') }}">
<label class="form-check-label" for="CheckRepetition">Activa para Repetición</label>
</div>
```

With Eloquent:

```
<div class="col-3 mb-3">
    {{ Form::label('Tarea Repetitiva Checkbox *') }}
    {{ Form::checkbox('repetition', $task->repetition, ['class' => 'form-switch ' .($errors->has('repetition') ? ' is-invalid' : '')]) }}
    {!! $errors->first('repetition', '<div class="invalid-feedback">:message</div>') !!}
</div>
```

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Look at the documentation : https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#checkboxes-and-radio-buttons The third parameter of checkbox is a boolean to set if checkbox is checked or not, you should use the 4th

Comment: Thanks Vincent but I've already tested it like this, it always returns true (even setting the value to false) and doesn't save the form. I do not understand why ...

```
                {{ Form::checkbox('repetition', $task->repetition, ['class' => 'form-control' . ($errors->has('repetition') ? ' is-invalid' : ''), 'value', false]) }}

```

Comment: With "1" value i have a message when is unchecked: "The repetition field is required"

{{ Form::checkbox('repetition', '1', $task->repetition, ['class' => 'switch-input' . ($errors->has('repetition') ? ' is-invalid' : '')]) }}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

My code:

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-2 mb-3">
                {{ Form::label('Tarea Repetitiva') }}
                {{ Form::hidden('repetition', '0') }}
                <div class="form-check form-switch">
                {{ Form::checkbox('repetition', '1', $task->repetition, ['class' => 'form-check-input' . ($errors->has('repetition') ? ' is-invalid' : '')]) }}
                </div>
                {!! $errors->first('repetition', '<div class="invalid-feedback">:message</div>') !!}
            </div>
        </div>
```